# JavaScript delete function not working

Tags: javascript, button, removeall

I am working on a small project where I have a function that doesn't seem to work! It's my delete function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var id = 0;
var addOpdracht = $('<a/>', {
   'class': 'btn btn-success',
   'id': 'addOpdracht'
}).on('click', function(){
    $('.panel-body').append(getExerciseBlock(id));
    id++;
}).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');

$('.jumbotron').append(addOpdracht);
 })


function getAddBtn(target, i){
 var addBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary'
            }).on('click', function(){
              $(target).append(getWordPartInput(i));
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-plus"></i>');
            console.log(target);
     return addBtn;
}


 function getRemoveBtn(target, i){
   var removeBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-danger'
            }).on('click', function(){
              $(target).remove(getWordPartInput(i));
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');
            console.log(target);
  return removeBtn;
 }



 function getExerciseBlock(i){
   var eBlock = $('<div/>',{
'id': i,
'class': 'col-md-12'
  });

  $(eBlock).append(getAudioBtn(i), getWordInput(i), getWordPartInput(i), 
getRemoveBtn(i), getAddBtn(eBlock, i));

  return eBlock;
}


 function getAudioBtn(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var audioBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-primary'
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up"></i>');
  return audioBtn;
}


  function getWordInput(id, cValue){
    cValue = cValue || '';
    var wInput = $('<input/>', {
                'class': 'form-group form-control',
                'type': 'text',
                'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[]',
                'placeholder': 'Exercise',
                'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput'
            })
 return wInput;
 }


function getWordPartInput(id, cValue){
  cValue = cValue || '';
  var wpInput = $('<input/>', {
                  'class': 'form-group form-control',
                  'type': 'text',
                  'value': cValue,
                  'placeholder': 'Syllables',
                  'id': 'SyllablesGetWordPartInput'
              });
  return wpInput;
}
```

The part that doesn't work is:

```
   function getRemoveBtn(target, i){
   var removeBtn = $('<a/>', {
                'class': 'btn btn-danger'
            }).on('click', function(){
              $(target).remove(getWordPartInput(i));
            }).html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');
            console.log(target);
  return removeBtn;
 }
```

The `getBtn` works, but my remove functionality does not work. 
What is it that prevents my code from working properly? The 'getAddBtn' gives me one input field extra each time I click on it, now I am trying to make my `removeBtn` do they same but this time it should remove one input field each time. 
A picture to clarify: please note the blue little "add" sign! that will provide extra input fields! the green big button isn't involved in the problem! when the blue button is being clicked it keeps on adding and adding input fields, but what if you click it too many times and you want to delete one? I hope this little EDIT helped a bit more in understanding what I mean. 
[image: I hope this gives a bit more clarification]

Comment: A [working code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help us most. And please change the name of the question. There is actual *delete* javascript keyword, so it is confusing

Comment: Also the code of your function `getWordPartInput(i)` will also help.

Comment: And, please, try to format your code in a bit more readable way

Comment: @LudovitMydla https://jsfiddle.net/DanDy/hqy73b0h/ a working example, the first red button works (half) and all the others dont, at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do few things here. You have to change your `getRemoveBtn` function to something like this:

```
function getRemoveBtn(target, i){
  var removeBtn = $('<a/>', {
      'class': 'btn btn-danger'
   }).on('click', function(){ 

       /* Select all inputs by going to parent first 
          and then selecting all child inputs with class 'syllable'
          I have added this class in your getWordInput() function
          as noted bellow  
       */             
       let syllableInputs = $(this).parent().children("input.syllable");

       /*
          Now when you have ALL inputs of specific div
          remove the last one.
       */
       syllableInputs[syllableInputs.length-1].remove(target);

   }).html('<i class="fa fa-minus"></i>');
}
```

That basically removes only the inputs from `div` where remove button is: `$(this).parent().children("input.syllable")`.

Second thing you **should NOT do** is to assign same ids in your `getWordPartInput` and `getWordInput`functions. The purpose of `id` is to be unique in your html document:

```
  var wInput = $('<input/>', {
            'class': 'form-group form-control', // Add class here instead of id
            'type': 'text',
            'name': 'question_takeAudio_exerciseWord[]',
            'placeholder': 'Exercise',
            'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput' // Don't do this. Use class
  })
```

But to be able to select those `input`s I've created an additional `syllable` class in your inputs : `'class': 'form-group form-control syllable'` and used that as a reference to pick every `syllable` input as you can see in my code: `$(this).parent().children("input.syllable");`

Comment: oke, and where should the 'class': 'form-group form-control syllable' go? in a totally new input I make or should I change the class of var wInput? you have commented "Add class here instead of ID" but there is a class and not an ID, so could u clarify this please? the ID was used so I could specify it for my CSS by the way. so unless u say it still is a bad practice i'll delete it, but the functionality wasn't much of it (in terms of sending it to the JSON file)

Comment: By the comment I meant that when creating inputs in `getWordInput` function, change the row `'class': 'form-group form-control',` to something like: `'class': 'form-group form-control syllable',` And use that new class `syllable` for formatting. Don't use `'id': 'exerciseGetWordInput'` (just remove that line from your code). It really is bad practice to use same `id` on multiple elements. You can specify your CSS for input using the new class `syllable`

Comment: one last question if u dont mind me, how am I using the id on multiple elements? aren't the elements just cloning? and with the syllable form-group form-control syllable I assume you mean the input that that creates the syllables? if so, then that should be getWordPartInput (just stating to be sure)

Comment: You can call it cloning or copying, but ultimately in the end there can be more than one element on your page with same [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id). That's not good. If that answers your question, please mark it as such.

Comment: yep, thank you very much for the time and effort you put into it! your code did the job!

Answer (score 0):

As per [jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/remove/), **remove** can be done in few ways:

**Example from docs:**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

**Option 1:**

```
$( ".hello" ).remove();
```

**Option 2:**

```
$( "div" ).remove( ".hello" );
```

> So, add a class attribute to the html element you wish to delete and
>   use one of the above syntax to delete it.

Comment: oke, but the input fields that are made (when clicked on the addBtn) can't have classes or IDs (from what I know, and if they can, how?), because they are made with the "getWordPartInput". so they don't exist untill I click on the little blue icon "add". and the red one should take away each input field I "added". but this should be done based upon the ID